# Formula to determine if a duplicate exists and then compare the duplicates following cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to figure out how to compare duplicate values found in rows with other cells in those rows.

Here are the conditions I'm trying to put together but I can't seem to figure them out.

```
1.  If there is a duplicate entry in Name then that row is filled "Green"  
2.  If the duplicate entries StartType or Status are different then fill them both "Yellow"
```

Both AppIDSvc should be Green.

Both AppMgmt should be green but the StartType and Status should be yellow.

Both AppXSvc should be green but the StartType and Status should be yellow.

```
Server 2016                     
Type    Duplicate   Core Unique Desktop Unique  Name        StartType   Status
Desktop No          No          Yes             AJRouter    Stopped     Manual
Desktop No          No          Yes             ALG         Stopped     Manual
Core    Yes         No          No              AppIDSvc    Stopped     Manual
Desktop Yes         No          No              AppIDSvc    Stopped     Manual
Desktop No          No          Yes             Appinfo     Stopped     Manual
Core    Yes         No          No              AppMgmt     Stopped     Automatic
Desktop Yes         No          No              AppMgmt     Stopped     Manual
Desktop No          No          Yes             AppVClient  Stopped     Disabled
Core    No          Yes         No              AppXSvc     Stopped     Manual
Desktop No          No          Yes             AppXSvc     Running     Manual
```

Comment: Do you have a concept of where to start? What have you tried?

Comment: I've gotten the green accross to work as well as red for uniques.  But I haven't figured out how to compare the duplicate entries found that have different starttype and status.  This is what I use for the Unique and Duplicates.
Duplicates =COUNTIFS($E$3:$E$304, $E3)<>1
Uniques =COUNTIFS($E$3:$E$304, $E3)=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could structure the conditions in multiple ways but here's one. The first condition uses `COUNTIFS` to find things that meet our green criteria but don't match our current value in Status or StartType. The second condition uses a plain `COUNTIF` to count instances of a given name in a column (our green criteria).

**First Conditional Format:**
*Range:* =$F$2:$F$11,$G$2:$G$11
*Condition:* =COUNTIFS($E:$E,$E2,$F:$F,"<>"&$F2)+COUNTIFS($E:$E,$E2,$G:$G,"<>"&$G2)>0
*Color:* Yellow

**Second Conditional Format:**
*Range:* =$A$2:$G$11
*Condition:* =COUNTIF($E:$E,$E2)>1
*Color:* Green

[image: Final Result Table]